# snowflake query

Tags: sql

Here I am calculating `retail_margin` and `retail_margin_pct` based on the `sell-in price` , `sell-out price` ,and `sell-out volume`

The code I am pasted here is the calculation for `retail_margin` and `retail_margin_pct`
Here we are doing average of 3 months for sales volume based on the `calday`

With this code I am getting results but getting huge values not accepted

Somebody help me with this code any corrections?

```
Select 
    Coalesce(Round(sales_volume*(so_price*(1-0.18)-si_price*(1-0.18)),2),0)  as retail_margin,
    Coalesce(Round(Divo(si_price*(1-0.18),so_price*(1-0.18))*100,2),0) as retail_margin_pct
From (
    Select 
        Sold_to,
        Ean,
        Sum( sales_value) as sales_value,
        Sum(sales_volume) as sales_volume
        Round(divo(sum(sales_value),sum(sales_volume)),2) as so_price,
        Round(divo(sum(si_sales_value),sum(si_sales_volume)),2) as si_price
    From (
        Select 
            A3Sold_to,
            A3.Ean,
            A3.Sales_value,
            A3.Sale_volume,
            Coalesce ( A4.si_sales_value,0) as si_sales_value,
            Coalesce ( A4.si_sales_volume,0) as si_sales_volume
        From (
            Select
                A1.Sold_to,
                A2.Ean,
                Round(coalesce (sum(A1.sales_value),0),2)   as sales_value,
                Round(coalesce (sum(A1.sales_volume),0),2)   as sales_value
            From (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Max(calday) as max_date,
                    Max(calday)-90 as min_date,
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140' and product_cd is not null
                Group by 1,2
                Order by 1,2
            )A5
            Inner join (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Calday,
                    Round(coalesce (sum(salesvalue),0),2) as sales_value,
                    Round(coalesce (sum(salescase),0),2) as sales_volume,
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140'
                    and product_cd is not null
                Group by 1,2,3
                Order by 1,2,3
            )A1
                On A5.sold_to = A1.sold_to 
                    and A1.product_cd=A5.product_cd 
                    and A1.calday<=A5.max_date 
                    and A1.calday>=A5.min_date
            Inner join (
                Select distinct 
                    Ean, 
                    Product_cd,
                    Category,
                    Sub_category,
                    Brand,
                    Sub_brand
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_md.dim_product 
                Where sales org='7140' 
                    and Ean!=' ' 
                    and product_cd is not null 
                    and base_uom='CS'
                Group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
                Order by 1,2,3,4,5,6
            ) A2
                On A1.product_cd=A1.product_cd 
            Group by 1,2
        )A3
        Left join (
            Select 
                Sold_to,
                Ean,
                Max(calday) as max_date,
                Max(calday)-90 as min_date,
            From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellin
            Where sales_org='7140' 
                and country_cd= '4025' 
                and product_cd is not null
            Group by 1,2
            Order by 1,2
        )A6
        (
            Select 
                Sold_to,
                Ean,
                Calday,
                Round(coalesce(sum(net_inv_value_in_lc),0),2) as si_sales_value,
                Round(coalesce (sum(salescases),0),2) as si_sales_volume
            from
            From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellin
            Where sold_to in ( 
                select distinct 
                    sold_to from 
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140' and product_cd is not null
                )
                and  sales_org='7140' and country_cd= '4025'
            Group by 1,2,3
            Order by 1,2,3
        )A4
            On A4.sold_to =A6.sold_to 
                and A4.Ean=A6.EAN 
                and A4.calday<=A6.max_date 
                and A4.calday>=A6.min_date
        On A3.Sold_to = A4.sold_to 
            and A3.Ean=A4.Ean
    )
    Group by 1,2
)
```

Comment: not the answer you are looking for, but it is a waste of compute to ORDER BY is a sub-select. also when you have DISTINCT you don't need a GROUP BY CLAUSE as they are the same things.

Comment: Also the way I would prove this out is to push the parts into CTE's instead of sub-select, and then test that those parts are correct, and then if the parts are good it's how you are putting it together.

Comment: And can we have some sample data (just some lines) and how you feel the values are wrong, and what you expect (for that sample data)

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle <> Snowflake - I have removed the conflicting tags... feel free to add back the single correct tag.

Comment: Also please make your title more descriptive of the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
           From (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Max(calday) as max_date,
                    Max(calday)-90 as min_date,
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140' and product_cd is not null
                Group by 1,2
                Order by 1,2
            )A5
            inner join (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Calday,
                    Round(coalesce(sum(salesvalue),0),2) as sales_value,
                    Round(coalesce(sum(salescase),0),2) as sales_volume,
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140'
                    and product_cd is not null
                Group by 1,2,3
                --Order by 1,2,3
            )A1
                On A5.sold_to = A1.sold_to 
                    and A1.product_cd=A5.product_cd 
                    and A1.calday<=A5.max_date 
                    and A1.calday>=A5.min_date
```

can become:

```
           From (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Max(calday) as max_date,
                    Max(calday)-90 as min_date,
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140' and product_cd is not null
                Group by 1,2
            )A5
            join (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Calday,
                    Round(coalesce(sum(salesvalue),0),2) as sales_value,
                    Round(coalesce(sum(salescase),0),2) as sales_volume,
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140'
                    and product_cd is not null
                Group by 1,2,3
            )A1
                On A5.sold_to = A1.sold_to 
                    and A1.product_cd=A5.product_cd 
                    and A1.calday between A5.min_date AND A5.max_date
```

in A2 you select six fields but only `EAN` is used. AND the ON is refering to `A1` on both sides. So if you numbers are wacked this might be it.

was:

```
             join (
                Select distinct 
                    Ean, 
                    Product_cd,
                    Category,
                    Sub_category,
                    Brand,
                    Sub_brand
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_md.dim_product 
                Where sales org='7140' 
                    and Ean!=' ' 
                    and product_cd is not null 
                    and base_uom='CS'
                --Group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
                --Order by 1,2,3,4,5,6
            ) A2
                On A1.product_cd=A1.product_cd
```

maybe should be:

```
             join (
                Select distinct 
                    Ean, 
                    Product_cd
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_md.dim_product 
                Where sales org='7140' 
                    and Ean!=' ' 
                    and product_cd is not null 
                    and base_uom='CS'
            ) A2
                On A1.product_cd=A2.product_cd
```

things like coalescve to zero aka `Coalesce( A4.si_sales_value, 0)` I would tend to use [ZEROIFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/zeroifnull.html) as it says what is happen.

Also I am not sure what JOIN is happening between A6 and A4, so am just leaving that alone.

But I would write it more like:

```
Select 
    zeroifnull(Round(sales_volume*(so_price*(1-0.18)-si_price*(1-0.18)),2))  as retail_margin,
    zeroifnull(Round(Divo(si_price*(1-0.18),so_price*(1-0.18))*100,2)) as retail_margin_pct
From (
    Select 
        Sold_to,
        Ean,
        Sum( sales_value) as sales_value,
        Sum(sales_volume) as sales_volume
        Round(div0(sum(sales_value), sum(sales_volume)),2) as so_price,
        Round(div0(sum(si_sales_value), sum(si_sales_volume)),2) as si_price
    From (
        Select 
            A3Sold_to,
            A3.Ean,
            A3.Sales_value,
            A3.Sale_volume,
            zeroifnull( A4.si_sales_value) as si_sales_value,
            zeroifnull( A4.si_sales_volume) as si_sales_volume
        From (
            Select
                A1.Sold_to,
                A2.Ean,
                Round(zeroifnull(sum(A1.sales_value)),2) as sales_value,
                Round(zeroifnull(sum(A1.sales_volume)),2) as sales_value
            From (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Max(calday) as max_date,
                    Max(calday)-90 as min_date,
                from rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                where sale_org = '7140' 
                    and product_cd is not null
                group by 1,2
            )A5
            join (
                Select 
                    Sold_to,
                    Product_cd,
                    Calday,
                    Round(coalesce(sum(salesvalue),0),2) as sales_value,
                    Round(coalesce(sum(salescase),0),2) as sales_volume,
                from rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                where sale_org='7140'
                    and product_cd is not null
                group by 1,2,3
            )as A1
                on A5.sold_to = A1.sold_to 
                    and A1.product_cd=A5.product_cd 
                    and A1.calday between A5.min_date and a5.max_date 
             join (
                select distinct 
                    ean, 
                    Product_cd
                from rgm_sales_gbl.int_md.dim_product 
                where sales org='7140' 
                    and ean != ' ' 
                    and product_cd is not null 
                    and base_uom = 'CS'
            ) as a2
                on a1.product_cd = a2.product_cd 
            group by 1,2
        ) as a3
        left join (
            select 
                sold_to,
                ean,
                max(calday) as max_date,
                max(calday)-90 as min_date,
            from rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellin
            where sales_org='7140' 
                and country_cd= '4025' 
                and product_cd is not null
            group by 1,2
        )A6
        (
            Select 
                Sold_to,
                Ean,
                Calday,
                Round(zeroifnull(sum(net_inv_value_in_lc)),2) as si_sales_value,
                Round(zeroifnull(sum(salescases)),2) as si_sales_volume
            From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellin
            Where sold_to in ( 
                select distinct 
                    sold_to from 
                From rgm_sales_gbl.int_txn.sellout
                Where sale_org='7140'
                    and product_cd is not null
                )
                and sales_org = '7140' 
                and country_cd = '4025'
            Group by 1,2,3
        )A4
            on a4.sold_to = a6.sold_to 
                and a4.ean = a6.ean 
                and a4.calday between a6.min_date and a6.max_date 
        on A3.Sold_to = A4.sold_to 
            and A3.Ean=A4.Ean
    )
    group by 1,2
)
```